# Serialization compatibility Java 7/8

Tags: java, serialization, java-8, java-7, compatibility

Is object serialization backwards compatible from Java8 to Java7?

I.e., does the Java serialization specification (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) guarantee that the following works: I compile class A into a Java8 application, serialize an object of A (into a file, say) and deserialize that object in a Java7 application (compiled with the same version of class A).

Could somebody point me to the exact part of the specification which specifically adresses different major versions? If there is none, from what part can I deduce said compatibility?

Note: Section 5.1 of the specification is about *class* version compatibility, but not about *Java* version compatibility.

Comment: Sure. That’s exactly what an explicit `serialVersionUID` is for.

Comment: @Holger Sure, but there is nothing about `serialVersionUID` in the question.

Comment: @EJP: it was, before the question has been entirely rewritten. I thought, you should have enough experience with Stackoverflow to know that posts can be edited and how to compare the time of an edit with the time of a comment…

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The specification hasn't changed between Java 7 and 8 (or 9), and it guarantees compatibility except in the cases noted in the Object Versioning chapter. Note also that there are warnings in every `javax.swing` class about this.

Answer (score 2):

> Could somebody point me to the exact part of the specification which specifically adresses different major versions? If there is none, from what part can I deduce said compatibility?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#a5849
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html

You could see that protocol version is 6 in both cases:

> Java Object Serialization Specification
>   version 6.0